# Number of connections in a hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, tree, network-analysis

I have a hash of arrays like the following:

```
my %HoA = (
    "M" => [ "L", "E" ],
    "L" => [ "I" ],
    "E" => [ "B", "C" ],
    "B" => [ "A" ],
    "C" => [ "A" ]
);
```

You can visualize it in this way:

```
    M
   / \
  L   E
 /   / \
I   B   C
     \ /
      A
```

Now, I would like to know the number of connections for every node:

```
M 6
E 3
L 1
B 1
C 1
I 0
A 0
```

With the *igraph* package in R this is straightforward but I am struggling to do the same with a hash of arrays in Perl.

Answer (score 8):

You can build graphs in Perl using the [`Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph::Directed) module

You need a `Graph::Directed` object

---

Here's an example

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Graph::Directed;

my %HoA = (
    "M" => [ "L", "E" ],
    "L" => [ "I" ],
    "E" => [ "B", "C" ],
    "B" => [ "A" ],
    "C" => [ "A" ]
);

# Build the graph
#
my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

while ( my ($from, $to) = each %HoA ) {
    $g->add_edge($from, $_) for @$to;
}

# Build a table of successors of each vertex
#
my %succ;

for my $v ( $g->vertices ) {
    my @succ = $g->all_successors($v);
    $succ{$v} = \@succ;
}

# Print the vertices in descending order of successors
#
for my $v ( sort { @{$succ{$b}} <=> @{$succ{$a}} } $g->vertices ) {
    printf "%s %d\n", $v, scalar @{$succ{$v}};
}
```

#### output

```
M 6
E 3
C 1
B 1
L 1
A 0
I 0
```

Comment: I didn't know about this module. Great suggestion, thank you!